# How to realize post query in asp web api

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I must solve it ->

Functionality:
create web api, asp core, ef code first (edited)

Introduce the API to create the following records: contacts, accounts, incidents (edited)

account cannot be created without contact

incident cannot be created without account

Validation:

if account name is not in the system -> API must return 404 – NotFound

if contact is in the system (check by email) -> update contact record,
link contact to account if it has not been linked previously.

Otherwise,
create new contact with first name, last name, email and
link just created contact to the account
create new incident, for account and populate incident description field

There are my Models:
Contact:

```
    [Index(nameof(Email), IsUnique = true)]
    public class Contact
    {
     [Key]
     public int Id { get; set; }
     [Required]
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     [Required]
     public string LastName { get; set; }
     [Required]
     public string Email { get; set; }

     public int? AccountId { get; set; }
     public Account Account { get; set; }


}
```

//contact Repository

```
public class EFContactRepository : IContactRepository
{
    private readonly Test_DbContext Context;
    protected readonly IMapper _mapper;
    public EFContactRepository(Test_DbContext context, IMapper mapper)
    {
        Context = context;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Contact> Get()
    {
        return Context.Contacts;
    }
    public Contact Get(int id)
    {
        return Context.Contacts.Find(id);
    }
    public void Create(Contact contact)
    {
        Context.Contacts.Add(contact);
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
    //public void Update(Contact updatedContact)
    //{
    //    Contact currentContact = Get(updatedContact.Id);


    //    currentContact.FirstName = updatedContact.FirstName;
    //    currentContact.LastName = updatedContact.LastName;
    //    currentContact.Email = updatedContact.Email;
    //    //Context.Entry(currentContact).State = EntityState.Modified;

    //    //Context.Contacts.Update(currentContact);
    //    Context.SaveChanges();

    //}       
    public void Update(Contact entryContact)
    {
        Contact currentContact = Get(entryContact.Id);


        currentContact.FirstName = entryContact.FirstName;
        currentContact.LastName = entryContact.LastName;
        currentContact.Email = entryContact.Email;
        Context.Contacts.Update(currentContact);
    }
        //_mapper.Map(entity, entityToUpdate);
        
        
    
        //    using (var db = Context)
        //    {

        //        db.Entry(entity).State = !Context.Contacts.Any(f => f.Email == entity.Email) ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
        //        db.SaveChanges();
        //    }
        //    return entity;
        //}
        public Contact Delete(int id)
    {
        Contact contact = Get(id);
        if (contact != null)
        {
            Context.Contacts.Remove(contact);
            Context.SaveChanges();
        }
        return contact;
    }
}
```

//Contact Controller

```
// GET: api/Contacts
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Contact>>> GetContacts()
    {
        return await _context.Contacts.ToListAsync();
    }

    // GET: api/Contacts/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Contact>> GetContact(int id)
    {
        var contact = await _context.Contacts.FindAsync(id);

        if (contact == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return contact;
    }

    // PUT: api/Contacts/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutContact(int id, Contact contact)
    {
        if (id != contact.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        _context.Entry(contact).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!ContactExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }

    // POST: api/Contacts
    // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Contact>> PostContact(Contact contact)
    {
        _context.Contacts.Add(contact);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetContact), new { id = contact.Id }, contact);
    }
```

Account:

```
     [Index(nameof(Name), IsUnique = true)]
     public class Account
     {
      [Key]
      public int Id { get; set; }
      [Required]              
      public string Name { get; set; }                              
      [Required]
      public ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
      public string? IncidentName { get; set; }
      public Incident Incident { get; set; }
     }
```

//Account Repository

```
public class EFAccountRepository : IAccountRepository
{
    private readonly Test_DbContext Context;
    public EFAccountRepository(Test_DbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Account> Get()
    {
        return Context.Accounts;
    }
    public Account Get(int Id)
    {
        return Context.Accounts.Find(Id);
    }
    public void Create(Account account)
    {
        Context.Accounts.Add(account);
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
    public void Update(Account updatedAccount)
    {
        Account currentAccount = Get(updatedAccount.Id);

        currentAccount.Name = updatedAccount.Name;
        currentAccount.Contacts = updatedAccount.Contacts;
        currentAccount.Incident = updatedAccount.Incident;

        Context.Accounts.Update(currentAccount);
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
    public Account Delete(int id)
    {
        Account account = Get(id);
        if (account != null)
        {
            Context.Accounts.Remove(account);
            Context.SaveChanges();
        }
        return account;
    }
}
```

//Account Controller

```
// GET: api/Accounts
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Account>>> GetAccounts()
    {
        return await _context.Accounts.ToListAsync();
    }

    // GET: api/Accounts/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Account>> GetAccount(int id)
    {
        var account = await _context.Accounts.FindAsync(id);

        if (account == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return account;
    }

    // PUT: api/Accounts/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutAccount(int id, Account account)
    {
        if (id != account.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        _context.Entry(account).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!AccountExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }

    // POST: api/Accounts
    // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Account>> PostAccount(Account account)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        bool hasData = _context.Accounts.Any(e => e.Name == account.Name);
        if (!hasData)
        {
            _context.Accounts.Add(account);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        _context.Accounts.Update(account);
        
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return CreatedAtAction("GetAccount", new { id = account.Id }, account);
    }
```

So, thans my query to Account POST method

```
     {

      "name": "string41",

      "contacts": [
                   {
  
          "firstName": "string",
          "lastName": "string",
          "email": "string44"
  
                   }
                   ]
       }
```

I tried to modify the controllers and methods of the repository, but in the task itself it is indicated that during the creation of the account, I must check whether the contact is already in the system, namely by his email, but when I try to implement it in the post method on behalf of the account, he just tries to create a new contact, not checking if there is already an existing one, and if so, it needs to be edited, namely First and Last Name

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please edit your post to include your existing code. Please also explain what you've already tried.

Comment: @Luke 
Added. So i hope, u can help me..
Actually, I don't now how to add cheking "Is Contact exist?" when i try add new Accoun

Comment: So you need to use `Context.Accounts.Find` to check if the Contact exist?What property you want to check?